# UILabel tap gesture not working when clicked

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have created a label I am trying to turn into a segue to another page, but before I can setup the segue I have to make the label clickable.  I have tried numerous different ways that have been mentioned here but cannot seem to get it to work correctly.  The way my code is set up, the label is created in an external class associated with a UICollectionView, this class is not in the same swift file that the `ViewDidLoad()` function is in.

Here is the creation of the label in the class file inside of its own class that is not related to the file that `ViewDidLoad()` is in.  The class that the label is in is being called in the `ViewDidLoad()` function, so the label and all of its properties are still being displayed.

Creation of label

```
 @IBOutlet weak var moreLabel: UILabel! = {

    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "See More..."
    label.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    label.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.textAlignment = .right

    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapMore))

    return label

}()
```

Function for the click

```
@objc func tapMore(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    print ("You tapped more")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added the gesture recognizer to the label...

**EDIT**

Even though you haven't added the recognizer to the label, as noted by `matt` this won't work anyway, as `self` does not exist in this context.

I'm more accustomed to using this format:

```
//@IBOutlet weak var moreLabel: UILabel! = {

lazy var moreLabel: UILabel = {

    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "See More..."
    label.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    label.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.textAlignment = .right

    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapMore))

    // add it to the label
    label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    return label

}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(moreLabel)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        moreLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        moreLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        ])
}

@objc func tapMore() -> Void {
    print("Tapped")
}
```

Comment: No, it still won’t work.  `self` is meaningless in this context.

Comment: Also the label is not getting into the interface and will vanish because the reference is weak. This is very bad code he’s shown us.

Comment: @matt - yeah... not sure about his comment *"the label is created in a swift file outside of the file that the ViewDidLoad() function is in"*.

Comment: Thank you for your input, the label is created inside of a class for my collectionview. Sorry I was not a bit more clear about that, so i'm not sure if putting all the code inside of the viewdidload would work because I have other things referencing the label inside of the collectionview.  I hope that makes sense @matt

Comment: @ohhmy097 - I think you've fallen into a common "trap"... you posted what you *think* is the relevant information, but you've left out the context that's needed to give you a proper answer. If you're still struggling with this, edit your question and include the full details. See [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You cannot say `target: self` in a property declaration initializer. There is no `self` yet. Move all that code into `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

- Set the frame property of the label because after UILabel() the frame is set to (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

> label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 24)

- Assign the gesture recognizer to the label

> label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)